# how to hover over menu and sub menu

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

With following code, I am able to hover and click on 1 level hierarchic. `ctl00_mnuMainn2 -> New`

```cs
public static void openFundNewPageTest()
    {
    NavigateFromMainPage("td#ctl00_mnuMainn2", "New");
    //driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("New")).Click();
    WaitForPageLoad();
    }

public static void NavigateFromMainPage(string objectIdentifier, string menuLink)
    {
    string js = "$(" + "'" + objectIdentifier + "'" + ").mouseover();";
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(js);
    driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(menuLink)).Click();
    }
```

If there are multiple level of submenu like `ctl00_mnuMainn2 -> Fund -> Hierachi -> New`
how can I make them work?

Also i am not able to identify link on page.

Comment: Can you provide the URL. We can do this using Actions class. Very easy

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
WebUtilities.executeScript(driver, "$('.context_menu').show()");
```

Replace '.context_menu' with your respective css selector.

Then you can find the element and click it.

Comment: Execute 2 scripts 1 for outer and 1 for inner. Finally click the element